# TypeError: [1, 2, 3].foreach is not a function

Tags: javascript, foreach

This code:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {

      [1,2,3].foreach( function (pic_num) {
        console.log(pic_num);
      } );

    }); // DOMContentLoaded

})();
```

Throws this error in the console: `TypeError: [1, 2, 3].foreach is not a function`.

Questions on this error usually turn out not to use an array (or list and collection) as the object of foreach, but mine **is** an array.

What gives?

Comment: The error says that `.foreach` is not a function, not that your array isn't an array.  `foreach` is undefined here, but you're trying to invoke it as a function, hence the error.  It should be `forEach`.  Try `[].foreach` in your browsers console; you'll get undefined.  Then try `[].foreach()` and you'll get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `foreach` to `forEach`

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {

      [1,2,3].forEach( function (pic_num) {
        console.log(pic_num);
      } );

    }); // DOMContentLoaded

})();
```